# how to draw a string in a GLKView mixed with OpenGL

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, opengl-es, quartz-2d

I want to be able to draw a string over the OpenGL window in my iOS app. What is the easiest way to do this? I know you can define a texture with letters and draw parts of that texture to create text - but this is quite a bit of work for what I am doing. I just want to be able to draw a simple string in the upper left of the window.

Is it possible to mix opengl with 2d drawing commands? I'm using `GLKView`, so I suspect it involves adding some code to `drawInRect`.

I am using OpenGL ES 1.1 for this.

Comment: Have you considered using a `UILabel` for this? You can add it as a subview to your `GLKView`.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution for this. If you add a label as subview to the GLKView then you can draw text over the opengl.